# Different test data than train data

Tags: r, regression, average, weather

I have a large dataframe (54160 observations) that needs to be split into a training and a test set. This should not be a problem, but in the dataframe there are several historical weather variables (per day, 2013-2018). These can be used for training, but not for prediction, because one cannot know the weather in advance. Therefore, I replaced these variables with the historical average per month (e.g. the average temperature in January is around 5 degrees Celsius).

Now I would like to do a regression in R and train my model on 75% of the data (with the original weather variables). Then I want to predict on the remaining 25% of the data (but with the replaced weather variables). How do I do this in R? Because essentially I'm dealing with two different datasets, an original one and a modified one. Thus: from the original one I need 75% for training, and from the modified one I need 25% for testing (but of course the data points should not overlap).

How do I make sure the data does not overlap? Or should I also train on the modified dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You are right in wanting to separate your training and testing data. To do this you need to randomly select 75% and then take the other 25%. This solution first randomizes the order of the data and then takes the first .75 and last .25 of the data.

```
weather_data <- data.frame(day = 1:50000,temp = sample(1:100,50000,replace = TRUE))

random.order <- sample(1:50000,50000)

weather_data <- weather_data[order(random.order),]

training_data <- weather_data[1:37500,]
test_data <- weather_data[37501:50000,]
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand but that it's not quite what I mean. What you're saying is what I would normally do with one dataset (and then make two of that: train and test), but this time I have a slightly modified dataset that should be used for testing but not for training..